# Spring Boot Devtools by Example

Tags: java, spring-boot

According to the [Spring Boot Devtools docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), devtools won't run in "production mode"; that is, if you execute your Spring Boot app with `java -jar ..,` then it won't use devtools' built-in JVM magic. However, the [Spring Boot starter docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) only show you one way of running your Spring Boot application...via `java -jar...`.

So first I'm wondering: **How do I run my Spring Boot app in non-production mode?** I know you can run your app with Spring Boot CLI (e.g. `spring run`), but is that the only way?

Also, the same devtools docs mention you can explicitly remove the devtools jar from your production binary by using some `excludeDevtools` option, but they never explain where/how to use this. Any examples/ideas here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) One example of running a Spring Boot app in non-production mode (i.e. not from the JAR) is from an IDE (most specifically Eclipse or IntelliJ), where you can launch the application from the main method, or using the Spring Boot launch support. This is the most practical use of Dev Tools as it allows to continuously watch the changes in your application without restarting.

2) `excludeDevTools` is an option of the Spring Boot Maven Plugin http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html or the Gradle plugin - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration.

So in your case it would be 

    `bootRepackage {
        mainClass = 'demo.Application'
        excludeDevtools = true
    }`

Comment: Thanks @Marius Bogoeivic (+1)! A few followups if you don't mind: **(1)** I see that I can run my app with the Spring Boot CLI (using a command such as `spring run ...`, etc). Is it possible to use this CLI to run your Spring Boot app w/ devtools (for hot swapping) as well as in [debug mode](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html#using-boot-running-as-a-packaged-application)? And **(2)**if I exclude dev tools, can you just confirm that devtools will *only* be excluded from the packaged uber-jar? Thanks again!!!

Comment: (2) Yes - that's its role - to prevent devTools from being packaged in the uberjar even if added as a dependency.

Comment: (1) I'm not very sure how `spring run` could work in this case, since devtools relies on the code being continuously recompiled - which `spring run` doesn't do (even in the case of Intellij, a project make is required to pick up changes). The good news is that you can use Gradle for running your app with devtools, using Gradle - here is an example https://dzone.com/articles/continuous-auto-restart-with-spring-boot-devtools.

Answer (score 1):

To start with Spring boot and devtools made development easier. Spring boot uses embedded servlet container ( tomcat,undertow,jetty) with this you can have production ready code even in non-production environment.

Coming to your question how to run Spring-boot application in non-production environments, we can run application directly from Spring tool suite IDE by right click -> run as Spring boot if it is local environment.

If the build tool used is maven then from command prompt mvn boot:run , if it is gradle then gradle bootRun from root folder of project location in command prompt. If you are packing your application as uber jar then Java -jar .., also if your environment is Linux you can start as a process.

Regarding ignoring devtools in production environment, Spring boot intelligently ignore devtools jar if we specify Spring-boot-devtools as optional scope in dependencies of your build tool(maven, gradle) . In gradle Spring boot gradle plugin takes care of ignoring devtools for final deployed jar or war

Update :: 
To debug a Spring Boot application run with Gradle, as seen at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-remote-debug-gradle-run596

Add this to your build.gradle file:

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [

"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" ]

In IntelliJ Idea IDE or STS, setup a new Debug configuration and in the options select "Remote". The defaults should be fine, but pay attention to the port number and transport type ("socket"). Have fun!

Comment: Thanks @rajadilipkolli (+1) - can `gradle bootRun` run your app in debug mode as well?

Comment: For the App and anyone looking for a way to debug a Spring Boot application run with Gradle, as seen at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-remote-debug-gradle-run596

Add this to your build.gradle file:

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [

"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" ]

In IntelliJ Idea, setup a new Debug configuration and in the options select "Remote". The defaults should be fine, but pay attention to the port number and transport type ("socket"). Have fun!